# A better way to pull an ID from a form submission Javascript/Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, post

Currently what I have coded up works, but it seems rather crude. Basically here's what I have (simplified):

JQuery ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.partDelete').click(function() {

        // TODO this seems like a dirty hack
        var split = this.id.split('_');
        if(split.length == 3) {
            $('#part_id').val(split[0]);
            alert($('#part_id').val());
            $('#removePartForm').submit();
        } else {
            alert('There was a problem removing the selected part');
        }
    });

</script>
```

The form I am using:

```
<form id="removePartForm" action="{% url remove_part %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="part_id" name="part_id" value="-1" />

    {% for part in current_build.parts.all %}
        <div id="{{ part.id }}_part_id" class="partDelete">remove</div>
    {% endfor %} 
</form>
```

All I'm trying to do is set the hidden input to take the part.id that has been selected by the user so that I can use it in my views.

For all I know this is the correct way to go about this, but I just have a feeling it isn't.  I am new to Django & JQuery so there may be some built in functionality for this that I haven't found yet.

Thanks for any suggestions that you may have!

## Solution (see mikaelb's answer below)

Javascript:

```
$('div.partDelete').click(function() {
    var selected_id =$(this).data("id");
    $('#part_id').val(selected_id);
    $('#removePartForm').submit();
});
```

HTML changes:

```
<div class="partDelete" data-id="{{ part.id }}">remove</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all; IDs shouldn't start with a number (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name).

Aside from that, you'd typically use the data-* attribute for setting IDs to communicate with JS from server side. The data-* attribute can be anything you want. So data-foo="" is a valid attribute.

**Example:**
HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-id="{{ part.id }}">
    <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () { // same as document read

    $(".button-class").on("click", function () {
        // Here "this" will be the element
        var id = $(this).data("id"); // same as getting attribute data-id
        // Could also use $(this).attr("data-id")
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Moved comment to make it more clear, changed the example to be more specific to OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't need to use the `.each` function after all. I can't believe I never knew about the `data-*` attribute!